# how to create a popup window in C#.net

Tags: c#

I have two different applications on different system.If a button pressed in one application i keep its record in Database and according to the record I want to popup a window in second application that notifying that Button is pressed in first application.

How could I do this? Is it feasible?

Comment: Is one application launched from the other? Are theese seperate windows of the same application?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing a record in the database, you can poll the database from second application and take the action based on the state. Once the request has been addressed, you can mark the record in the database.

Comment: again with polling the database?

Answer (score 0):

You said different systems (i.e. computers). right?
In that case you would have to send some sort of message to the other application to initiate a popup.

Is the Database you are storing the value accessible by both Computers ?
In that case if a little delay (few seconds) is acceptable between pressing a button in an app on one computer and the popup on the other, you could also use some sort of polling. So the other system where the popup would show, can check the database at regular intervals (say every 10 seconds) for the record that is set by the Button press and if present then show the popup.

But if such a delay is not acceptable, then you would need to use some networking between the two applications. So a message can be sent directly to the popup generating application from the button one.

**Update**
Yes you will need a continuously running exe on the other (popup) system for either of solutions, be it database polling or networking.

*For Database Polling :*

- Simply create a windows application.
- Add a timer object to it with an interval of as many milliseconds you want between polls (for 10 seconds set it to 10000)
- Then write database retrieval code in the Tick event Handler for the timer control.

*For Networking*: Take a look at following question - [networking in .net/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210738/networking-in-net-c)

Comment: Thanks!! so for that I have to create an continues running .exe which keep track of database entries? Can you plaese give me sample code to write such exe.

Comment: Polling the database? Really?

Comment: I know its not efficient to use the polling technique, that's why I pointed to Networking between two applications. But if its a light application with database on intranet, then a polling interval of 10 seconds or more (if acceptable) can work.

Comment: I searched on the net and found that ther is a way called Query Notifications . Will it work fine?

Comment: I looked it up, and it should work fine for your purposes. I'll add it to my answer later.

Comment: yes..Query Notifications  solved my problem. thanks to every one

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server as your database you may be able to use [SQL Server Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx)

This discussion is similar...
[Notification about Database Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286413/notification-about-database-change)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using polling from the 2nd app, you can be notified when the table changes. You can use a class called **SqlDependency** for this. A good example can be seen on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/chatter.aspx). In fact, the example sounds very close to what you're looking for.